# Port cost relation to data rate capacity

Tags: data, port-channel

Why is it that the allocated port costs lower for links with higher data rate capacity? Since a highter data rate capacity lowers the frame transmission timing, shouldn't it be more costly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but think of cost as time. It takes less time to send a frame on a higher-speed interface, so less time means less cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For routing protocols, “cost” might be better called “preference.”  Presumably you would prefer higher bandwidth links, so they have lower cost.

Answer (score 3):

In routing, *cost* is a measure for how much effort it takes to process and forward a packet or stream over a link or a path. As Ron has pointed out, this pretty much corresponds to the time the data occupies a link, therefore a higher data rate means less cost. (The *worth* may be the direct opposite. ;-)

Depending on the perspective, *metric* may also be commonly used (its more on the interface level).